# Passing a predicate to a predicate in a lambda form

Tags: c#

I am negating a predicate. I have done it with a method. But I am struggling with a syntax for a lamba expression. How to do it in lambda?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var words = new List<string> { "falcon", "wood", "tree",
      "rock", "cloud", "rain" };

    Predicate<string> hasFourChars = word => word.Length == 4;
    // Predicate<bool> Negate = Predicate<string> fun => word => !fun(word);

    var words2 = words.FindAll(Negate(hasFourChars));

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', words2));
}

static Predicate<T> Negate<T>(Predicate<T> predicate) 
{
   return x => !predicate(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the next approach:

```
Predicate<string> hasFourChars = word => word.Length == 4;
Predicate<string> negate = word => !hasFourChars(word);
```

And then you can use predicate `negate`:

```
var words2 = words.FindAll(negate);
```